# Converting to number from string with special characters

Tags: regex, oracle11g, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have a input column with below values.

```
1.2%
111.00$
$100.00
aa
ss
```

Output expected

```
1.2
111.00
100.00
null
null
```

I am trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE and tried replacing every character that is not a digit or "." so that `1.2%` will become `1.2`.
Here is the query I tried but this didn't work.

```
regexp_replace('%1.aa2', '[^[\d|\.]]', '')
```

Can anyone suggest how to do that? and what I am doing wrong? I am working on Oracle 11.2 database with pl/sql developer.

Comment: Just use `[^\d.]+` in pattern.

Comment: this didnt worked, it replaces everything except ".". Here is the query I used

select regexp_replace('%1.aa2', '[^\d.]+', '') from dual

Comment: I guess you'll have to escape the backslash too in that case. Try `\\d` instead of `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

Use  POSIX class for matching digit chars ie `[:digit:]`. So this negated class `[^[:digit:].]` should match any character but not of dot or digit.

```
regexp_replace('%1.aa2', '[^[:digit:].]', '')
```

Comment: how is this different from 

 '[^[\d.]] 

?

Comment: don't know whether oracle supports `\d` . If it supports, then it would be `[^\d.]`

Comment: Thanks @Avinash raj. [:digit] worked fine. I am sure that oracle supports '\d' as well. Check this statement



select regexp_replace('asas12313', '\d', '-') from dual

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[^0-9.]` regex and replace with empty string:

```
with testdata(txt) as (
  select 'ss' from dual
  union
  select 'aa' from dual
  union
  select '$100.00'      from dual
  union
  select '111.00$'             from dual
  union
  select '1.2%'             from dual
)
select regexp_replace(txt, '[^0-9.]', '')
from testdata;
```

Result of an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d143f/1):

[image]